# TCP checksum fails C++

Tags: c++, tcp, checksum

I did a function to calculate the TCP checksum but it fails and i dont know why. I give to the function the bytes of the packet that i just catched in the network and its size.

At first i calculate the pseudo-header tcp (with wrong tcp length but this is not the only problem because sometimes it has cero and the problem persist.

I let you the code here:

```
//http://www.arcesio.net/checksum/checksumTCP.html
u_char* tcp_checksum(const u_char* datos, int tamaño)
{
    u_char *checksum = new u_char[2]();
    uint16_t sumando = 0;
    bitset<17> total;
    bool ack = false;
    if (datos[47] == 0x10) ack = true;

    //sumo ip origen e ip destino
    for (int i = 26; i < 33; i++){
        total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        if (total[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
        i++;
    }

    //sumo el byte de ceros y el numero de protocolo TCP
    total = sumando + (uint16_t)(0x06);
    sumando += (uint16_t)(0x06);
    if (total[16] == 1)
        sumando++;

    //aqui sumaría el tcp len no se calcular aún.
    //[IP Total Length] - (([IP IHL] + [TCP Data offset]) * 4)
    //Aquí sumaríamos el TCP len ¿cuanto es?.
    /*total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[38] << 8) + datos[39]);
    sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[38] << 8) + datos[39]);
    if (total[16] == 1)
        sumando++;*/

    //sumo todo el campo de cabecera con el checksum a cero
    for (int i = 34; i < 54; i++){
        if (i != 50){
            total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
            sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
            if (total[16] == 1)
                sumando++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    //sumo todo el campo de datos a lo que teníamos.
    for (int i = 55; i < tamaño - 1; i++){
        total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        if (total[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
        i++;
    }

    //invertimos y pasamos a dos bytes el resultado.
    sumando = sumando & 0xFFFF;
    sumando = ~sumando;
    checksum[0] = (sumando >> 8) & 0x00FF;
    checksum[1] = sumando & 0x00FF;
    return checksum;
}
```

I know that TCP length is wrong, but this is not the only error in this implementation of TCP checksum, what more fails?

Regards, and thank you.

Comment: It would be good if you described what you mean by "fails". What do you do, what happens and how is that different from what you expected to happen?

Comment: Can you post a sample TCP frame that you are trying to calculate the hash for?

Comment: thanks for your anwers, it fails because when i compare the tcp checksum that i calculated with this function with the real tcp checksum of the packet catched in the network  its not the same. I catched the packets of the network with winpcap and i use "tcp" filter for the capture, the checksum tcp is on bytes 51 and 52, and is not the same that i am trying to get. Regards! Sorry for my english XD

Comment: Be wary of TCP checksum offload hardware in some network cards. It can mess with checksum capture.

Comment: This is a TCP packet: 70188ac334aba1bc1b86737d080045000028d4c84000ed06fe57b9284041c0a8009d08334ab673b7‌​496726e5f3765010f485d63b0000000000000000                               As we can see the checksum is in the byte 51 and 52 and it values 0xd63b, but when i pass the packet to my function i have other checksum so it fails, why?

Comment: Please i have been working for 2-3 weeks with this hard, i really need help.